# Apigee Unable to resolve host - of internal target service

Tags: apigee

I deployed an internal service to Apigee, but after deployment requests are failed because Apigee can't resolve the internal DNS of target service.

This is the message i get when I'm trying to access the service via Apigee:

{"fault":{"faultstring":"Unable to resolve host ","detail":{"errorcode":"protocol.http.NoResolvedHost","reason":"TARGET_CONNECT_HOST_NOT_REACHABLE"}}}

Where can i configure to the Apigee how to forward DNS request to internal DNS server?

Tried to change from DNS to IP address, but the service wouldn't accept IP.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it requires Service DNS Peering.

As mentioned in this page:
[Service producer unable to access consumers Private DNS zones](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/kcs-service-producer-unable-to-access-consumers-private-dns-zones-000006005)

It requires to properly configure DNS resolve in the VPC where the Apigee attached it's subnets (prefix 22 and 28) for Private  Service Connection.
Than configure DNS peering from that VPC to the service, with the command [gcloud services peered-dns-domains create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/peered-dns-domains/create).

**Important:**

If you are connecting Apigee to target service via Private Service connect and Endpoint Attachment, DNS configuration in the VPC must resolve the DNS of target service to the IP Address of the Endpoint Attachment, which can be found in Endpoint Attachments in Apigee console, or Apigee blade in GCP console.
It's looks like a weird IP address as example - 7.2.20.13